# how can i control fan speed on ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: fancontrol

is there any way to check the fan speed? and increase/decrease the speed?
This is because my PC goes above 80deg but i cant hear any fans. So yes i don't want a gas stove so is there any way to like control the fans?
In windows there is an app called Speed-fan, so I need an alternative.

Ubuntu (xubuntu) 21.10
4GB RAM

```
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`              mehul@Lenovo 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           ------------ 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         OS: Xubuntu 21.10 x86_64 
    -yddddddddddddddddddddhdddddddy-       Host: 90LX0091IN ideacentre 510S-07I 
   odddddddddddyshdddddddh`dddd+ydddo      Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic 
 `yddddddhshdd-   ydddddd+`ddh.:dddddy`    Uptime: 1 hour, 50 mins 
 sddddddy   /d.   :dddddd-:dy`-ddddddds    Packages: 2567 (dpkg), 8 (flatpak),  
:ddddddds    /+   .dddddd`yy`:ddddddddd:   Shell: bash 5.1.8 
sdddddddd`    .    .-:/+ssdyodddddddddds   Resolution: 1024x768 
ddddddddy                  `:ohddddddddd   DE: Xfce 4.16 
dddddddd.                      +dddddddd   WM: Xfwm4 
sddddddy                        ydddddds   WM Theme: Greybird 
:dddddd+                      .oddddddd:   Theme: Greybird-dark [GTK2/3] 
 sdddddo                   ./ydddddddds    Icons: elementary-xfce-darker [GTK2/ 
 `yddddd.              `:ohddddddddddy`    Terminal: xfce4-terminal 
   oddddh/`      `.:+shdddddddddddddo      Terminal Font: Monospace 12 
    -ydddddhyssyhdddddddddddddddddy-       CPU: Intel i3-9100 (4) @ 4.200GHz 
      :yddddddddddddddddddddddddy:         GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Gra 
        .+yddddddddddddddddddy+.           Memory: 2231MiB / 3818MiB 
           `-/osyhddddhyso/-`
```

Comment: Is it possible that dust is physically stopping the fans from spinning? If you're confident in doing this, consider taking off the cover and blowing out the fans w/ compressed air (not a vacuum) and removing any obvious dust

Comment: uh no its kinda not a gaming pc lol

Comment: CPU: Intel i3-9100 (4) @ 4.200GHz 
Intel CoffeeLake-S GT2 GPU

Comment: i have the same pc as you have the ideacentre 510s and as far as i know it is not possible to controll the fanspeed on this model when running any version of ubuntu.i hope somebody can find a solution to this problem because the fan speed is too low so the cpu gets a bit too hot at times.there is no option to increase the fanspeed in bios.

Comment: oh ok thanks for your help.

Comment: is there any workaround???

Comment: the only things you can do for now is to install cpupower-gui and lower the max frequenzy of your cpu and to keep the cpu cooler clean from dust buildup.i have changed the thermal paste it did not help and there is no updated bios/uefi for ubuntu.

Comment: @karel sensors detect and lm sensors does not solve this problem,i have been researching this problem for a couple of years now and it does not look like any solution exists.

Comment: okay thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Change out the fan for a fan with higher rpm. e.g if your fan does 1500 rpm @ 12 Volts look for one that does 2000 rpm @ 12 Volts. There are fan that do 4000 rpm, but they make a lot of noise. 
The curve of the blades and the space between the blades and the chassis (of the fan) also influence the performance of the fan. 
Use the fansticker and Dr. Google to get information about the fan. Then you know size and rpm. 
Another thing you can do is make a duct between the fan and the air inlet in the sidepanel. Cartboard from a shoebox and duct-tape will do this trick. Measure the distance between fan and sidepanel. Add 1 or 2 cm at each side. Fold the 1 or 2 cm 90 degrees outwards and tape it to the sidepanel. Fold it a little bit at the fanside, so that it will slide over the fanhousing ( just the fanhousing, not the metal part of the cooler.)
With the duct it draws air directly from the outside of the case, which is cooler than air from inside the case.
Of course you can change the cpu-cooler all together for a better one. (This is the most expensive solution, but the most professional one.)

Comment: Get some old fans and cut the center ( the actual fan ) out. Stack them, one on the fan of the cpu cooler, then 1 on top of that and so on, unill you reach the sidepanel. If there is no air intake, make one. Angle grinder, dremel, or just drill some holes in it. That way your CPU cooler receives fresh air from outside the case ( instead air from within which is heated air ). If there is place in the case for more fans, use them. Be aware of the airflow. The cooler your components run the longer they 'live'.

Comment: @ Joepie Es Airflow is important. Also refresh the air in the case! Intake and outlet fans. I use old fans (cut out the actual fans from them middle ) and stack them, instead of your cardboard solution. Also on the cheap, since they were worn out. The modern day 'elite' solution is 3D printing.